# Structuring Firebase database for Messages with Auto ID

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been structuring my Firebase database so that messages end up being stored sequentially. Unfortunately, firebase must have made a change because now numbers no longer sort sequencially, so I have to store data a different way and still get the messages to come out in the correct order. The mainstream way to do this is to store a the message data by Auto ID. I do not understand how to properly retrieve the data though to get it back in the correct order. I have read a lot of code and docs and still that question lingers.

So, to clarify: This is what a message in my Database would look like:

- **id123**

  - **NAME**: John
  - **MESSAGE**: Hi guys!
  - **DATE**: 11/11/16
  - **TIME**: 6:04 PM

I stored the id in that format ("id"+numberOfPost). It is considered good practice to store by Auto ID, but I do not know how to retrieve the data in its proper order. Ex. of my Database structure with Auto ID.

- **Kr7r2kupqerhrepqbuixd**

  - **NAME**: John
  - **MESSAGE**: Hi guys!
  - **DATE**: 11/11/16
  - **TIME**: 6:04 PM

This would sort to be in the "K" section, and the post after it could start with a "B", making the database out of order. How do I structure the database to use Auto ID and yet be able to get messages in the proper order?

My code for posting a message looks like this:

```
 self.firebase.child("Chats").child(chatID!).child("id\(counter)").child("MESSAGE").setValue(message!)

     self.firebase.child("Chats").child(chatID!).child("id\(counter)").child("FIRST_NAME").setValue(fn!)

     self.firebase.child("Chats").child(chatID!).child("id\(counter)").child("LAST_NAME").setValue(ln!)

     self.firebase.child("Chats").child(chatID!).child("id\(counter)").child("ID").setValue(id!)

     self.firebase.child("Chats").child(chatID!).child("id\(counter)").child("DATE").setValue(date!)

     self.firebase.child("Chats").child(chatID!).child("id\(counter)").child("TIME").setValue(time!)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "it could start with a B"? It cannot, as auto IDs are chronological.

Comment: Is Auto ID not an automatically generated ID? Firebase sorts the data alphabetically so randomly generated IDs would break the system @vzsg

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. Please check this blog post on how the push IDs (FB's take on automatic IDs) work: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html